# Java - ascii checking

Tags: java, ascii

I have the next code:

```
        t= (int)(Math.random()*8+1)+96; //ascii table
        if (t!= 96){
                choose[(int)(t-97)] = 1;
                r[0] = (char)t;}
    }
```

I try that in `r[0]`, there would be only characters from `b` to `h` (`'a'` is not allow). When I run it, I see that sometimes `r[0]` contains `'a'`. What can be the reason?

Comment: I thought it goes like that: `(int) (Math.random() * (high - low) + low);` meaning: >=x und <y or [x,y[

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'a' is [ASCII 97](http://www.manpagez.com/man/7/ascii/), and you're not preventing that.

Why don't you just pick a value from 98 ('b') to 104 ('h') in the first place, instead of allowing 'a' to be picked and then rejecting it?

(I'd also suggest using `Random.nextInt` instead of `Math.random`, and character literals instead of magic numbers, but...)

Answer (score 0):

The key

```
a= 97 //asCII
```

but you have if condition on 96 key also after calculations you are not verifying the last key value.  see [ASCII TABLE](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: I am late the legend is here..:-)

Answer (score 0):

It will be printed if Math.random() returns a value less than 0.1249. Then  Integer value becomes 97 and thus 'a' is printed. The ASCII value of a is 97. You are checking whether it is not 96 only.